# Multiple RabbitMQ Consumers DotNet Core

Tags: c#, .net-core, rabbitmq

We have an application that needs to have multiple consumers for the same query. The Data is of such nature what the "Competing Consumer" is not a problem as the messages can get processed in any order and independent. My question is, as RabbitMQ does its own Thread Management etc, what is the best approach to create multiple consumers picking messages of the same queue? Looking at this basic example of a simple consumer:

```
var factory = new ConnectionFactory() { HostName = "localhost" };
using(var connection = factory.CreateConnection())
using(var channel = connection.CreateModel())
{
    channel.QueueDeclare(queue: "hello",
                            durable: false,
                            exclusive: false,
                            autoDelete: false,
                            arguments: null);

    var consumer = new EventingBasicConsumer(channel);
    consumer.Received += (model, ea) =>
    {
        var body = ea.Body.ToArray();
        var message = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(body);
        Console.WriteLine(" [x] Received {0}", message);
    };
    channel.BasicConsume(queue: "hello",
                            autoAck: true,
                            consumer: consumer);

    Console.WriteLine(" Press [enter] to exit.");
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

I believe multiple instances of `channel.BasicConsume(...)` needs to be created, but what is the best way to do that? With a [TaskScheduler](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.taskscheduler?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=net-5.0) or Multiple Threads or what?

I can introduce service layers and tidy everything up but just need to know what is the safest way to go about it.

All the reaseach I found so far points not not creating multiple consumers but in our case its a requirement.

Comment: Why not create a queue per consumer? Each queue can be bound to a single exchange.

Comment: RMQ messages are delivered on round-robin based on connection, I would prefer to go running multiple instances of consumer running at same time so that it generates multiple connections. multiple instances of 'channel.BasicConsume(...)' will go on single connection I think.

Answer (score 0):

One simple way is, you can have two console application like this, then run both of them together.